# Laravel Headers being stripped in middleware

Tags: php, laravel, apache, nginx

I am using laravel on nginx. Custom headers (HTTP_BEARER) are being sent to the 1. bootstrap/app.php and public/index.php but do not reach the middle. What could be the problem. The same project is sending headers on apache, on my local machine.